# Turing criteria for Sel'kvo glycolysis model

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, biology

I have the Sel'kov reaction diffusion model for glycolysis as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
u_t=D_uu_{xx}-u+av+u^2v\\
v_t=D_vv_{xx}+b-av-u^2v
\end{eqnarray}

How can I obtain the values for $D_u$ and $D_v$ for a pattern formation via Turing criteria. The last equations model's glycolysis in 1D. In two dimensions:

\begin{eqnarray}
u_t=D_u(u_{xx}+u_{yy})-u+av+u^2v\\
v_t=D_v(v_{xx}+v_{yy})+b-av-u^2v
\end{eqnarray}

Using the same Turing criteria, how can I obtain the exact analitic forms for $D_u$ and $D_v$ diffusive constants. I'm using the Turing criteria as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
p(\sigma)=\mid J-\sigma I-\lambda D\mid=0\\
Re(p(\sigma))<0
\end{eqnarray}

where $J$ is the Jacobian matrix evaluated in the EP $(b,\frac{b}{a+b^2})$, $Re(p(\sigma))$ es the real part of the equation and $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue for the linealization and vectorization to obtain a lineal PDE wich is $\lambda=\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}$ and $D$ is the diffusive matrix as follows $D=\begin{pmatrix} D_u & 0\\ 0 & D_v  \end{pmatrix}$.

I've trying to obtain the relation for $D_u$ and $D_v$ and I can't do it, not in the $1D$ case or the $2D$ case. Please somebody helps me out.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is more widely known as the Gray-Scott model; a nice overview and description of the Turing instability analysis can be found [here](http://th.physik.uni-frankfurt.de/~fschubert/).

To find out more about the relationship between the real part of the eigenvalues of the Jacobian and its trace and determinant, see my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637878/2-dim-dynamical-system-ivp/1638768).

I believe that, with these two ingredients, you'll be able to obtain the required bounds on $D_u$ and $D_v$.